# Check if value 'abc' and not 'abc aze' contained in textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I want to know if the value 'Type de prise' exists in MySQLBDDColumns.Text

I get the value I want to know if it is contained in Texte_Caractéristiques.Text

But only I have the value 'Type de prise' and the value 'Type de prise du chargeur' so if 'Type de prise du chargeur' was created before when it will try to know if 'Type de prise' exists. say yes while I would like it to be no.

Here is my code:

```
for (y = 0; y <= (Texte_Caractéristiques.Lines.Length - 1); y = y + 2)
{
    if (MySQLBDDColumns.Text.Contains(EnleverAccent(Texte_Caractéristiques.Lines[y])))
    {
        if (y == Texte_Caractéristiques.Lines.Length - 2)
        {
            Sauvegarde_Dans_BDD();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CreateColumnsIfNotExists(EnleverAccent(Texte_Caractéristiques.Lines[y]));
        Get_ColumnsBDD();

    }
}
```

So I would like to have a method that would allow me to know if MySQLBDDColumns.Text contains the value 'Type de prise' without which I return a true value if 'Type de prise du chargeur' exists or another value that can contain the same text

I have also tried with Regex, IndexOf and equals but I can not find any solutions for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want an exact match, does comparing equal work?

```
string.Equals(MySQLBDDColumns.Text, EnleverAccent(Texte_Caractéristiques.Lines[y]), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I've also added the condition of ignoring case to the comparison, but this can be removed as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work ...

If you prefer the richtextbox 'MySQLBDDColumns' contains the existing columns in MySQL and 'Texte_Caractéristiques' contains all the columns that exist or will be created if it does not exist.

Each line corresponds to a column in each richtextbox.

I was thinking of doing a test if (MySQLBDDColumns.Text.Contains('Type de prise' + " ") but I did not achieve a valid result

Comment: If there are multiple SQL columns per entry (represented by lines in your text box), then what is the **delimiter** between each column of data? Also, is it important that the SQL data is put into a textbox, or can we use a more efficient way of searching the data?

Comment: I retrieve features from a site via HTMLAgilityPack and store it in 'Text_Characteristics'
First Line = Name column
Second Line = Value of the first column
Third Line = 2nd Name column
Second Line = Value of the second column

Is not important to stock SQL Data in textbox

Comment: How does the MySQL data get put into MySQLBDDColumns? Can we instead do an SQL query?

Comment: I get MySQL data with query "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" + bddname + "`"
So I would send the request for each line and MySQL manages whether to add or not?
I did not think about this solution!
I test her on the way back, I spend my morning on it I want the solution today ahah

Comment: That would be my recommendation, instead of storing the whole SQL table locally in a textbox. That could get very inefficient if the table is large enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !!
I still use 'Text_Characteristique' to display the values recover in my WinForms so it does not change big things ^^
I remastered my query to 'ALTER TABLE `" + bddname + "` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `" + text + "` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `" + MySQLBDDColumns.Lines [MySQLBDDColumns.Lines.Length - 1] + " ` '
I just had to add 'IF NOT EXISTS' ^^

Comment: Sounds like it is, but the original question is now obsolete.